# Prevent hard switch off in smartphones using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, security

While most smartphones now require a PIN/password before we can switch it off, there are some ways to get around this.

For eg. I own a Samsung M30. If I'll press the Volume Down + Power button at the same time, the device will switch off.

I'm trying to develop an android app that lets the user temporarily disable the hard switch off. Is there a way to prevent this programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. This behaviour is enforced at a very low level. Even system apps can't modify this behaviour.

Comment: Oh, I see. Any workarounds? Like, any way I can implement something that makes it difficult for a person to hard switch-off a mobile phone? Actually I'm trying to develop a personal safety app, and it can really use a feature like this, otherwise there won't be a point if someone can just switch off your phone after stealing it.

Comment: No. There is literally nothing you can do, it's enforced at hardware or modem level.

Comment: Oh okay..Thanks a lot!